# How to implement a decrementing for loop in Julia?

Tags: loops, for-loop, julia, decrement

I know that in `python` I can do something as follows.

```py
for i in range(10, 0, -1):
    print(i)
```

Which will output:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

I'm very much new to `julia` and I know I can create normal loops as follows.

```
for i=1:10
    println(i)
end
```

Intuitively, I tried something like as follows (since I thought it behaved similar to python's `range([start], stop[, step])` function).

```
for i=10:1:-1
    println(i)
end
```

Although it didn't fail, it didn't print anything either. What am I doing wrong?

Is there an intuitive way to loop backwards in `julia`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
julia> for i=10:-1:1
           println(i)
       end
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

or this

```
julia> for i=reverse(1:10)
           println(i)
       end
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

As @phipsgabler noted you can also use:

```
julia> range(10, 1, step=-1)
10:-1:1
```

to get the same result again (note though that you have to use `1` as a second index).

From my practice `range` is usually more useful with with `length` keyword argument:

```
julia> range(10, 1, length=10)
10.0:-1.0:1.0
```

(notice that in this case you get a vector of `Float64` not `Int`)

Comment: Ah... I was thinking in terms of python... Thanks...

Comment: Also note that `reverse` for ranges is efficient. If you write `reverse(1:10)` you just get `10:-1:1` as a result.

Comment: Or `range(10, 0, step=-1)`, to stay close to the Python syntax.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Thank you for commenting (just note `1` not `0` in `range` as a second argument)